# Are the Yoga Sutras of Patanjali available online in Devanagari anywhere in copy/pastable text format?

Tags: reference-request, yoga-sutras

I am looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Sutras_of_Patanjali, do these exist in copy/pastable Devanagari anywhere online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, available [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_yoga/yogasuutra.html):

> ॥ प्रथमोऽध्यायः ॥  ॥ समाधि-पादः ॥
>
> अथ योगानुशासनम् ॥ १.१॥
>
> योगश्चित्तवृत्तिनिरोधः ॥ १.२॥
>
> तदा द्रष्टुः स्वरूपेऽवस्थानम् ॥ १.३॥
>
> वृत्तिसारूप्यमितरत्र ॥ १.४॥
>
> वृत्तयः पञ्चतय्यः क्लिष्टाऽक्लिष्टाः ॥ १.५॥
>
> प्रमाणविपर्ययविकल्पनिद्रास्मृतयः ॥ १.६॥

So, it's in Devanagari and copy and paste are also working.

Comment: Unfortunately this site has a restrictive usage license, is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://yogasutrastudy.info/yoga-sutra-translations/ysp-in-devanagari-sanskrit/
This site is an addition to the one given above.